# Seagate External Hard Drive locked, can only read not write

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, ntfs

**What Happened:**

I plugged in my Seagate backup hard drive today (not Time Machine) after a few months and my computer can read the drive but not write to it.

**Two obvious problems:**

1) The drive is formatted as NTFS
2) The drive has (from top to bottom) "Read & Write", "Read-only", "Read-Only" permissions.

I know what you are going to say, but the NTFS writing software that Seagate has to write to these type of drives doesn't work on this version of macOS I guess the upgrade killed it because I have used the drive before on previous versions.  When I try to run the software mac says "the developer needs to update this software to work with this version of Mac".  I know each of those two problems are the cause of this issue but I am unable to find a solution.  The "Ignore Ownership on the Volume" checkbox in the drive's show info box is not there.

Does Seagate have new software for writing to these drives? (I use a lot of open-source stuff, but for this I would prefer seagate official software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seagate provides an OEM-version of Paragon's Microsoft NTFS for Mac. The software is availbale at: [Paragon Driver for macOS (10.10 and above)](https://www.seagate.com/support/external-hard-drives/portable-hard-drives/goflex/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/). Direct link: [NTFS_for_Mac](https://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/support-content/external-products/backup-plus/_shared/downloads/NTFS_for_Mac.dmg)

The installer build date is Sep 12, 2019. The installer's info.plist indicates compatibility:

```
MACOSX_MAX_VERSION 10.15
```

After downloading and installing it (and probably rebooting your Mac), you should have normal access to the NTFS volume again.

---

This OEM-version only works for Seagate drives!